# Fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS boot issues

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

I've recently being trying to sort out an issue with a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04LTS. I have a Nvidia 970 video card, so I need the drivers. When I complete the install and then boot, I get the flashing cursor.

To fix that, I need to follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) -  Under Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time. But no matter what I do, I cannot get Grub to load. I've tried, both <kbd>shift</kbd> keys, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys. None of these work.

When I try the install with additional 3rd party software, I get to running post-installation trigger update-notifier-common and installing flash and it sits for hours (was on for 9 hours, connected via Ethernet to the router).

Answer (score 0):

This article, [Restore GRUB with Super GRUB2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wizard-restore-grub-with-super-grub2-disk/) should help.

Also if there is any way you can access a terminal, either before login with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or after with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, I would give

```
sudo update-grub
```

a try in the terminal. That should update your GRUB configuration.